# Is using var self = this a good way to sync between a class and events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's look at this simple code example (it's written in angularjs for the simplicity, but this happens all the times in JavaScript):

```
angular.module('app',[]).
directive('myDir', function(){
    this.state = {a:1, b:2};

    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            elem.on('click', function(){
                // "this" is not the class but the element
                this.state.a++;       
                this.state.b++;
                console.log(this.state);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

When the onclick callback's going to be invoked, the "this" will not be the directives function but the element itself.

So we all know the trick here and we create a closure and use `var self = this` to complete the work.

```
angular.module('app',[]).
directive('myDir', function(){
    // create a closure for the rescue
    var self = this;
    this.state = {a:1, b:2};
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            elem.on('click', function(){
                self.state.a++;       
                self.state.b++;
                console.log(self.state);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Ok - this works and I've done this so many times, but I'm asking myself if this is the best way to do something like this?
This always looked like a bad design workaround to me.
Is there a better way to sync between a class and user events?

Comment: some use `_this`, or `vm`

Comment: Why you think it as bad design?\

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about working code and would be better suited on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @IngoBürk You can practically say that on most questions here. Stack overflow isn't only a 'my code doesnt work - fix it' site. And I'm not asking for a code review. I'm asking for a different way to do something(concept) and the code is simply an example.

Comment: to be fair, you really _couldnt_ say that about 'most questions here'. if i could downvote a comment for being plain wrong, i would. but you are also correct in the sense that a concept doesnt demand a review.

Comment: @AmirPopovich I've changed my mind. Since you are asking about a general strategy and not a particular piece of code, codereview isn't the right place. I'll retract my vote.

Comment: @200_success If you read my last comment, you will see that I already changed my mind and retracted my vote for that very reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your particular example I would judge as bad, but perhaps not for the reason you're thinking. If you see the modified version at http://plnkr.co/edit/K66o8tmRtnnfk8NZ8YPf?p=preview

```
app.directive('myDir', function(){
    // create a closure for the rescue
    var self = this;
    this.state = {a:1, b:2};
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            elem.on('click', function(){
                self.state.a++;       
                self.state.b++;
                // Using global scope (seen as a bad thing)
                console.log(self === window);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

then the `self` you're defining is actually equal to `window`, and so you're actually saving state to the global scope. This is because the function that defines the directive isn't the target of a `new` statement, and so `this` has its default value, which is `window`.

If the function is the target of a `new` statement, such as a `controller` or a `service`, then setting `self = this` is fine. However, in a `directive` or a `factory`, then `this` isn't changed from its default value of `window`. In these cases I would just define a local variable

```
var state = {a:1, b:2};
```

and access it from closures.

An alternative is to use something like `bind` on each event handler, to change what `this` refers to in it. However, there could be times when you want the default binding inside the event handler, so sometimes needing to use `bind` and sometimes not, I suspect could lead to more debugging time spent, as you wouldn't have a consistent method for writing these.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The window thing is simply for this example you can always wrap you code in a function wrapper. I'm still looking for a way to do this differently.

Answer (score 0):

It is acceptable in services and controllers, but within directive's nested function scopes it looks messy - and also wrong. `this` is defined only in `compile` (and it refers to DDO), but neither in directive factory function nor in pre/postlink.

The better and cleaner way is to provide the context to callback function, so it knows (and so do you) what context it operates on.

```
       elem.on('click', angular.bind(state, function(){
            this.a++;       
            this.b++;
            console.log(this);
        }));
```

The alternative (native to ES5) way is

```
        elem.on('click', function(){
            this.a++;       
            this.b++;
            console.log(this);
        }.bind(state));
```

It can be considered the recommended one if the lack of support from IE8 isn't an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's similar to the one @Shashank Agrawal provided above. Using bind will work but is it really a better solution?

Comment: Better for what? But generally it is, this way the function isn't dependent on parent function's scope, and you don't have to change its contents if global variable changed its name somehow. In some cases you may stick to this/self instead (like you tried to do), but only when you mimic OOP in JS, so this is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

Although the approach you are using is also good, but yes, there is another best way you can write in any javascript code using `bind()` method.

```
angular.module('app',[]).
directive('myDir', function(){
    // create a closure for the rescue
    var self = this;
    this.state = {a:1, b:2};
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            elem.on('click', function(){
                self.state.a++;
                console.log(this.state.a == self.state.a);
            }.bind(self));
        }
    }
});
```

`bind` changes the context of the code. You can pass anything for the context. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
The bind approach is not a clean solution and you are still using the closure.